# Is the openshift Basic Walkthrough still working?

Tags: openshift, walkthrough

I keep fingers crossed that this writing appears somewhere near RedHat OpenShift.

Is this walk-through still working?
https://docs.openshift.com/online/pro/getting_started/basic_walkthrough.html

My experience from today is, that creating a Project worked fine.Then I got stuck.
Did not see anything that is related with JavaScript.
Could someone point me into the right direction?

I could choose between Overview, YAML, Workloads and Role Bindings

[See screenshot from webbrowser for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIaML.png)

Comment: The UI you're showing in your screenshot is for OpenShift Online Starter (based on OCP 4.3), however the docs you reference are for OpenShift Online Pro (based on OCP 3.11). For viewing the catalog, you should switch the "Administrator" dropdown to "Developer". Then use Add > From Catalog